# man page search - how can I turn off the highlighting after matches found?

Tags: man, less

When using man pages, a commonly used feature is to use `/` then a search term to get to a word of interest.

Once found, all matches remain highlighted - this can often be distracting when I just want to read the man page.

I'm sure its a simple key combo, but how can I turn the highlighting off once the matches are found?

- `ESC` does nothing
- `q` obviously quits out of man page completely

Note: I'm on Ubuntu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're on Ubuntu, the *pager* used to visualise man pages is probably GNU `less`.

As you can see after pressing <kbd>h</kbd>:

> ESC-u                Undo (toggle) search highlighting.

In most terminals, it should be equivalent to <kbd>Alt+U</kbd>.

Comment: got it, thanks. after years of find man pages were probably less help than google, I had "learned" not to bother with looking to bash docs for help etc. But as master Yoda said "*You must unlearn what you have learned, and give bash docs a go*"

Comment: @user4668401, `man` has nothing to do with `bash`. `bash` is a command to interpret command-lines (a command-line language interpreter), `man` is a command to read manual pages.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, once I thought about it, of course you are right. I quickly looked at <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page> to get a better feel for the relationship. tried `$man man` which gives a man page for man itself. and interestingly found this in the **History** section of wikipedia page *In the first two years of the history of Unix, no documentation existed. The Unix Programmer's Manual was first published on November 3, 1971. The first actual man pages were written by Dennis Ritchie and Ken Thompson*.